# MySQL JOIN Statement to filter rows by selected linked attributes

Tags: mysql, join

lets say i have the following two MySQL-Tables:

**item:**    _ID,_CAT_ID,...

**item_attribute:**
    _ID,_ITEM_ID,...

i want to (filter items) get ONLY items which have **ALL** selected attributes (1,32,555,...an array of selected attributes )

something like this:

```
SELECT  _I.* 
FROM  item _I
INNER JOIN item_attribute _IA
ON (_I._ID = _IA._ITEM_ID AND (_IA._ID=1 OR _IA._ID=132, ...))
WHERE _I._CAT_ID=? ORDER BY _I._LAST_UPDATE ASC;"
```

this "wrong" statement returns items when one(due to OR) of the  linked ids found, what i want is: only items which have all linked attributes.

if i change

```
(_IA._ID=1 OR _IA._ID=132 OR...)
```

to

```
(_IA._ID=1 AND _IA._ID=132 AND ...)
```

no matches and this makes sense, but how to rewrite the statement to get correct matches?

**UPDATE:**

here is a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f8ebe/6

```
CREATE TABLE item
    (`id` int, `pid` int, `name` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO item
    (`id`, `pid`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 'A'),
    (2, 2, 'B'),
    (3, 2, 'C')
;
CREATE TABLE att
    (`id` int, `pid` int, `name` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO att
    (`id`, `pid`, `name`)
VALUES
    (7, 1, 'red'),
    (7, 3, 'red'),
    (2, 1, '30cm'),
    (1, 3, '40cm'),
    (5, 2, 'blue'),
    (1, 2, '40cm')
;
SELECT * 
FROM  item;

SELECT * 
FROM  att;

/* expected: items which are red AND 40cm, result should be then only item C (id=3)*/

SELECT  _I.name 
FROM  item _I
INNER JOIN att _IA
ON (_I.id = _IA.pid AND (_IA.id=7 AND _IA.id=1))
WHERE _I.pid=2 GROUP BY _I.id;
```

SOLUTION http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f8ebe/8 (using Drews Answer):

```
SELECT  _I.name,count(_IA.id) as theCount 
FROM  item _I
INNER JOIN att _IA
ON (_I.id = _IA.pid) AND _IA.id in (7,1)
WHERE _I.pid=2
group by _I.id
having theCount=2
```

Comment: how about in(...). What is the point of the join again, if you are truly only using the first table, and the attr are hardcoded? Or do the join (on id of course) where table 2 attr in ( ... )

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Drew, thanks, but in(...) returns true if one or more attribute matched right? but what i want is if all attributes are in the specified (selected)list

Comment: dang good thing that wasn't an answer of mine, huh? How about if you know there are 10 attrs. And there **aren't** dupes in an intersect. If you do a count along with the in() and it equals 10, well there you go. All or nothing

Comment: I see the concept is what Kostas did below. I believe you deleted the question and brought it back, so check his out. I believe his has an extra layer of wrapping but I haven't gotten my head into it. I think the whole thing can be done in 7 lines

Comment: If you can provide an SQL Fiddle to check this out.

Comment: Oh, i was so close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is 7 lines of code, reading the tidbits from your question:

```
SELECT  _I.col1,_I.col2,count(_IA._ID) as theCount 
FROM  item _I
INNER JOIN item_attribute _IA
ON (_I._ID = _IA._ITEM_ID) AND _IA._ID in (1,32,555)
WHERE _I._CAT_ID=? ORDER BY _I._LAST_UPDATE ASC
group by _I.col1,_I.col2
having theCount=3
```

Note that `theCount` alias is allowable in a `having` clause.

Also note I put in col1 and col2 in line one, expand accordingly. The point is to list them, so the `group by` in line6 can mimic them for the non-aggregated columns. The value in line 7 must match the count of the values in the in `clause`

Comment: thank you, it tested your code here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f8ebe/8 and it returns results as expected. i will test it on my real project with some critical use cases and if it work, i will mark your answer as accepted

Comment: do i have to care about non-aggregated columns in GROUP BY even if i group by primary keys? take a look please on the comments of Kostas Answer.

Comment: what do you mean care about

Comment: if that is your style and it always work, sounds great

Comment: so i do not have to list the columns in the GROUP BY clause and i don't have the problem discussed in this post http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ ?, NOTE the comment of Roland there!

Comment: I simply have no comment on that, in fact I did not even read it, for reasons of precedence

Answer (score 1):

It should bring all the items that have 3 particular item attributes (red, 40cm, large).

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22848/1)

```
SELECT kk.*
FROM item AS kk
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT aa.id
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT bb.id
        FROM item AS bb
        INNER JOIN att AS cc 
        ON bb.id = cc.pid
        WHERE cc.name IN ('red', '40cm', 'large')
        GROUP BY bb.id 
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
    ) AS aa
) AS _aa
ON kk.id = _aa.id;
```

Result:

```
id  pid name
3   2   C
```

Comment: Try the updated answer and please tell me if it works because i am curious.

Comment: +1 yes your solution works, many thanks, but i used the answer of Drew, it is simpler, i don'T like the usage of 3 SELECTs and 2 joins for such simple issue.

Comment: Yes, don't worry. It was almost the same but I almost always use an additional INNER JOIN for grouping to avoid something like this: http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: woow, please take a look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f8ebe/27, and tell me if is it a problem to return _I.* and GROUP BY the primary key _I.id ? do i have the Problem which is disscussed in the link you posted even if i group by primary keys?.

Comment: To tell the truth i can't tell and for this reason i avoid using columns in SELECT that are not in GROUP BY or an nonaggregated column ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html )

Comment: hmm, from the docs of MYSQL: "The query is valid if name is a primary key of t or is a unique NOT NULL column", but i am still not sure!